# Build a nested map of arbitrary depth from an array of keys and a value

Tags: dictionary, go

I'd like to be able to write a GoLang function to take an array of keys and a value (i.e. `keys={"a", "b", "c"}, value=123`) then build a data-structure of nested maps where the positional index in the array corresponds to the depth in the nested map, and the value is assigned to the last key. For example, given the above keys and value, I want to build the following dictionary structure

```
 {"a":{"b":{"c":123}}}
```

Below is the code I currently have. The issue is that the resulting map is as follows

```
{"a":{}, "b":{}, "c":123}.
```

Any advice as to how I should amend this/why it's happening would be much appreciated.

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type dict map[interface{}]interface{}

func main() {
    vals := []interface{}{"a", "b", "c"}
    // create a dictionary
    d := make(dict)
    d.Set(vals, 123)
    // print it
    fmt.Println(d)
}

func (d dict) Set(keys []interface{}, value interface{}) {
    d2 := d
    fmt.Println("Initial dict: ", d2)
    keylen := len(keys)-1
    for _, key := range keys[:keylen] {
        // if key exists, recurse into that part of the dict
        if entry, ok := d2[key]; ok {
            d2 := entry
            fmt.Println("Entered level in dict: ", d2)
        } else {
            d3 := make(dict)
            d2[key] = d3
            d2 := d3
            fmt.Println("Created new level in dict: ", d2)
        }
    }
    d2[keys[keylen]] = value
    fmt.Println("Final dict: ", d2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have overcomplicated your solution. This recursive algorithm should do:

```
func set(d dict,keys []interface{}, value interface{}) {
   if len(keys)==1 {
      d[keys[0]]=value
      return
   }
   v, ok:=d[keys[0]]
   if !ok {
       v=dict{}
       d[keys[0]]=v
   }
   set(v.(dict),keys[1:],value)
}
```

You have to add code to handle the case where you're resetting a value (i.e. when v.(dict) type assertion might fail). Otherwise, you can recursively descend the map, and consume the keys at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's works just as I wanted. In hindsight I had over-complicated this. I'm pretty new to golang, is the v.(dict) an implicit type conversion? And this would attempt to convert a non-dict type if returned from the indexing of the current dict?

Comment: It is a "type assertion". `v.(dict)` will return the underlying value as a `dict` if it is really a `dict`. It'll panic otherwise. Use `d, ok:=v.(dict)` to test, that will return `ok=false` if the underlying value is not a `dict`. Read more here: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15